# Convert the string with datetime format-"yyyyMMddhhmmssfff" to "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM) before exporting DataTable to excel

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, epplus, excelpackage

I am exporting the result from a database to excel using ExcelPackage(EPPLUS nuget package).
The datetime field from the database is in string and in the format - yyyyMMddhhmmssfff which is not readable in excel after exporting-ex- 20191211034422455. So i need to convert this to readable format like
DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM or any other readable format. How do i achieve it. Do i need to parse each row and convert explicitly? And for conversion, do i have to first convert it to datetime and then to string again?

My current code Snippet

```
//Method which reads data from database 
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConnStrng))
{
    sqlcon.Open();
    string query = "Select Vehicleid,Speed,Datetime from VehiclDBk where Speed>30 and Datetime between '" + startDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
    valRes = new DataTable();
    sqlda.Fill(valRes);
    DBView.DataSource = valRes;
    sqlcon.Close();
}

// Method which exports data when user presses export button
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
     ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
     ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(valRes, true);
     pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(savefile.FileName));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Also is there a possibility that may be i can just convert it to DateTime and export as DateTime instead of string to datetime and again to string before exporting

Comment: Are you sure you're storing these values as strings in your database? Good database design would store them as DateTime (or equivalent) objects.

Comment: Yes, its been stored as string. Not sure why this was decided as this database exists from beginning

Comment: Don't use strings, use dates and set the correct date style instead. Modifying the cell value doesn't change how it's formatted. It can make Excel treat that value as a string instead of a date though, breaking any date-related formulas

Comment: PS: You don't to load a DataTable, you can use LoadFromDataReader. Even if you want a DataTable, you don't need SqlDataAdapter to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Should convert it to DateTime and then to string again.

In case you got a DateTime having milliseconds, use the following formatting (Link live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/16GAn0))

```
string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff";
string dateTime = "20191211034422455";
var x = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result = x.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM"); // In my opinion, You just convert to Date to use instead of then to string like this.
```

Comment: Do i need to do it for all rows explicitly before exporting?

Comment: Just to nit-pick, you don't "have to" convert to a DateTime. You could just do it using substrings.

Comment: This won't work. Excel will either *not* recognize the string as a date, or do so and use its default date formatting instead of the string's value

Comment: Yeah, If I were in his shoes, I could just convert to DateTime only instead of To string

Comment: True that. I will convert to datetime instead of string again. @PhongNguyen: in the solution given, im not able to pass my datatable.rows[1][0] as first argument to parseexact